# Docker swarm overlay network not working properly between all nodes

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have 3 remote servers, say *server1*, *server2*, and *server3*, with three IPs *ip1*, *ip2*, and *ip3*. I use *server1* to initiate a swarm, using `docker swarm init`, and let the other two servers join the swarm as workers. Everything's working fine in `docker node ls`.
Afterwards I create an overlay network, using `docker network create --driver overlay mydrupal`, and a test drupal service, using `docker service create --name drupal --network mydrupal -p 80:80 drupal`.

The problem is that I cannot use all the IPs to load the drupal webpage. After some research I found out that if the container is running on *server1* or *server2*, I can use *ip1* and *ip2* to load the website, but *ip3* doesn't work; and if the container is running on *server3*, I can use *ip3* to load it, but *ip1* and *ip2* fail. I should note that all TCP and UDP ports necessary for swarm are open between the three IPs.